# Best way to rip DVD movies to ISO files

Tags: dvd, iso-image, ripping

I'm trying to backup my DVD collection.
I have Handbrake, and will eventually experiment with the best settings to use.

For now, I'd like to backup the DVD's to ISO files, that i can mount and then use Handbrake on later, or burn back on to DVD should the original get damaged.
I have a WD TV box that is capable of playing ISO files also.

What's the best program for doing this?
I'm not so much concerned with file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DVD Decryptor to decrypt in ISO mode.  Also, there is a setting in there that collates all the VOB files into a single .VOB file.   Once you have a single VOB then there are lots of options such as using [AVIDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) to rip it to video.   If you dont collate the VOB then you have to worry about multiple VOBs during ripping and thats a hassle.

Never use anything other than Handbrake or AVIDemux.  IMHO, they are the best.

Comment: vlc can just play the vob.