# Creating DVD backups including interactive menus

Tags: ripping

I want to rip movies from DVD, including interactive menus and extras, so they can be played using regular media players or XBMC.

How can I do this?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: @CharlieRB Some questions can be trivially reworded to remove the software recommendation parts. There's nothing actually wrong with those questions.

Comment: @CharlieRB You should really only VC a question if it's unsalvageable. If you can't do it yourself, you might want to leave a comment to point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: @BloodPhilia VC? Google gives me Venture capital, Victoria Cross, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines ccTLD, Vanadium carbide, and Visteon Corporation ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen VC = Vote to Close (:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DVD ripper for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/4387/dvd-ripper-for-windows), [Best way to rip DVD movies to ISO files](http://superuser.com/questions/66922) and *many* more questions about DVD ripping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DVD Decrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk/) is a tool that can copy your DVDs to your hard drive keeping the structure completely intact. Due to the nature of the tool I make no assertions about the legality of using it within your country as under the DMCA or equivalent it may be illegal.

Windows will no longer recognize the copied files as a DVD though, so a player such as [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.org/) can be used to play them, you'll need to open the main `video_ts.vob` file in order to see the menu.